# os.walk not giving right path

Tags: python, os.walk

I am using the following code to open files from a directory.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./Boards"):
#Eliminate hidden files
files=[f for f in files if not f.startswith('.')]
for f, file in enumerate(files):
    print "ROOT: " + str(root)
    fileName=os.path.join(root,file)
    print fileName
```

When I run this i get this error

```
ROOT: ./Boards/AbuseSupport
./Boards/AbuseSupport/thread_title_11151.xml
ROOT: <Element 'board' at 0x1048ae450>
```

Can anyone explain how this happens and how I can fix it

Comment: The actual error I get is   

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parseXML.py", line 13, in <module>
    fileName=os.path.join(root,file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 68, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'endswith'`  

Which I know is caused by the fact that I'm getting an Element back, but I don't know why I'm getting an Element or really why the root is changing at all

Comment: I feel like we're missing an important part of the code. Also, could you fix the indentation ?

Comment: Inside my Boards directory I have multiple sub directories (ie AbuseSupport) that each contain xml files. I want to get the xml files so that I can open and parse them

Comment: I am assuming 'Boards' is in the same directory you are running this script.  If it is, you can just do `os.walk('Boards')`.  Not sure if it will fix it, but based on your error, it might not like the `/` character.

Comment: I changed it to just be os.walk('Boards') and it gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're **reusing** the `root` variable while you're walking the directory and parsing XML at the same time. After you've parsed one XML file, the `root` variable became the root element of parse tree, but in next iteration of the loop, you are still using `root` variable as the directory name.

Comment: THANK YOU! I never thought to look at how I was parsing my xml. You are absolutely correct. Kinda embarrassed by that rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

I created a base directory structure of:

```
/Boards
/Boards/a.txt
/Boards/b.txt
/.ssh
```

I used the following code:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./Boards"):
    #Eliminate hidden files
    files=[f for f in files if not f.startswith('.')]
    for f, file in enumerate(files):
        print "ROOT: " + str(root)
        fileName=os.path.join(root,file)
        print fileName
```

And I got the following response:

```
>> ROOT: ./Boards
>> ./Boards/a.txt
>> ROOT: ./Boards
>> ./Boards/b.txt
>> ROOT: ./Boards
>> ./Boards/c.txt
```

Mac OS 10.8.3 - Homebrew Python 2.7.3

I think you issue is that somehow you have assigned root to an XML Element object.  Is there other code using an XML library?